# Use Images instead of radio button and get the checked value and pass it to a h2 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using images to display radio buttons, but I am running into  trouble in getting the checked value and passing to a label. I am able to click on a image and set the radio button to checked, but if I click any another image, this images radio button also gets checked so now I have 2 radio buttons checked, I only want the one with the image selected and pass that value to h2 tag. Here is link for jfiddle showing a demo

[jFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pepin/qezz3bo9/6/)

```js
$('#thumbnails1').delegate('img','click', function(){
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
    });
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.swatch-colors li{float:left;margin:5px;padding:0;width:32px;height:32px}.swatch-colors  li .swatch-img{cursor:pointer;display:block}
label.lbswatches > input{visibility:hidden;position: absolute;}
label.lbswatches > input + img{cursor:pointer;border:2px solid transparent;}
label.lbswatches > input:checked + img{border:2px solid #f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="thumbnails1" class="noul swatch-colors">
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Cherry Red"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/ff0000/fff" class="full swatch-img" alt="Cherry Red" title="Cherry Red" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Irish Green"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/2fff00/fff" class="full swatch-img" alt="Irish Green" title="Irish Green" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Jade Dome" type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/1e7d07/1e7d07" class="full swatch-img" alt="Jade Dome" title="Jade Dome" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Orange"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/e69410/e69410" class="full swatch-img" alt="Orange" title="Orange" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
</ul>
<h2 id="colorselected"></h2>
```

Thanks and appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Javascript click event:

```
$("#colorselected").text($(this).attr("alt"));
```

That just updates the text in the h2 with the alt text from the last image you clicked. Does what you wanted right?

Might be worth unchecking the previous checked box too.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class like `.radio01` to the radio inputs.

```
$('#thumbnails1').delegate('img','click', function(){
       $(this).closest('ul').find('.radio01').attr('checked',false);
       $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
   });
```

EDIT: this works!

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution. Wrap your `<ul>` inside a `<form>` element.

```js
$('#thumbnails1').delegate('img','click', function(){
        $(this).prev().attr('checked',true);
    });
```

```css
ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.swatch-colors li {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
    width:32px;
    height:32px
}
.swatch-colors  li .swatch-img{cursor:pointer;display:block}
label.lbswatches > input{visibility:hidden;position: absolute;}
label.lbswatches > input + img{cursor:pointer;border:2px solid transparent;}
label.lbswatches > input:checked + img{border:2px solid #f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>    
    <ul id="thumbnails1" class="noul swatch-colors">
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Cherry Red"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/ff0000/fff" class="full swatch-img" alt="Cherry Red" title="Cherry Red" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Irish Green"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/2fff00/fff" class="full swatch-img" alt="Irish Green" title="Irish Green" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Jade Dome" type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/1e7d07/1e7d07" class="full swatch-img" alt="Jade Dome" title="Jade Dome" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
<li><label class="lbswatches"><input name="swatch_color" value="Orange"  type="radio"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/32/e69410/e69410" class="full swatch-img" alt="Orange" title="Orange" width="32" height="32"></label></li>
</ul>
</form>
<h2 id="colorselected"></h2>
```